# How to add a Background and logo to SharePoint site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

At the moment I am creating site followed by adding background and logo separately.

Is there a way to do achieve this at site collection level so that it will be inherited automatically to every sub-site created.

Comment: by background do you mean you are applying some css?

Comment: by designer .. i think it is not practicable...becuase you want the classical branding solution. That allows you to set the css and masterpage (with logo). Look here https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-branding-and-design-capabilities

Comment: yes apply css so that i reflect in all the sites created

Answer (score 0):

The best (and modern) way to achieve this is to add a javascript via custom action and than replace the content. I'd recommend to use JQuery.

Example for the Logo:

**JQuery**:

```
$('#suiteBar .ms-core-brandingText').html('HTML_OF_YOUR_LOGO');
```

**Plain Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById('suiteBar').getElementsByClassName('ms-core-brandingText').item(0).innerHTML = 'Logo';
```

If you want to style your site via CSS (e.g. add a background) you could add alternate CSS:

**Add Alternate CSS**

```
clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
website = clientContext.get_web();
website.set_alternateCssUrl('/SiteAssets/css/global.css');
website.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert('success');}, function(sender, args){alert('failed: ' + args.get_message());});
```

(this is javascript you can add via your JS console in the Browser (F12 => Console))

**Add JS as a custom action:**

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var website = clientContext.get_web();
var collUserCustomAction = website.get_userCustomActions();
var customActionOBJ = collUserCustomAction.add();
customActionOBJ.set_location('ScriptLink');
customActionOBJ.set_title('Global JS');
customActionOBJ.set_sequence(1000);
customActionOBJ.set_scriptBlock('document.write(\'<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/javascript/global.js"></scr\' + \'ipt>\');\n ');
customActionOBJ.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){alert('success');}, function(sender, args){alert('failed: ' + args.get_message());});
```

The best way is to include central JS as custom action and styles as alternate CSS and then include othe files from there (best via SOD or CSS-include).